# Lazy Loading in custom ORM

Tags: java, jdbc, orm, lazy-loading

I am currently working on developing a simple Java web application without using an ORM.

It is a layered architecture. I use annotations to 'map' the columns from my domain class to my persistence layer where the repositories are.

My `DefaultRepository` is using reflection to get the field names and build the queries. I just use this one instead of making a separate one for each domain (such as user, order, product).

It looks like this:

Repository:

```
public abstract class DefaultRepository <TYPE extends DefaultDomain<TYPE>>{

    public int insert(Connection con, TYPE entity){};
    public int update (Connection con, TYPE entity){};
    public int delete (Connection con, TYPE entity){};
    public int findById(Connection con, int id){};
    ...

}
```

I want to implement lazy loading to load the orders of each user only when requested. This preferably happens in the repository in the `findById()` where I map the result set to my `TYPE` (domain class).

How would I go about implementing this foreign key relation/ one to many/many to one in general?

An idea was to make an annotation with the specific repository and then call the `findAll()` method in there when the order list is called.

For example:

```
public class Order extends DefaultDomain{
    @ManyToOne(repository=UserRepository.class)
    private User user;

}
```

Is that the right way? Is there a different/better approach to this?

Comment: You ARE using an ORM.  You are choosing to write your own.  The annotations you wrote are exactly the ones that JPA uses.

Comment: Yes thank you, I worded it poorly. I tried looking into how JPA/Hibernate does this but couldn't find anything code-wise, just how to use it.

Comment: You can use JPA annotation

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)

Comment: @Mazen thanks but I'm trying to develop this myself and not use the ways provided by JPA or Hibernate

Comment: I know but I don't know why you want to reinvent the wheel ??

Comment: @Mazen well its for a small application and I have always wanted to try doing this myself, I dont want to reinvent the wheel, Im just asking for the best approaches for this problem